# Is it advisable to use USER_NAME as the object_id in user details collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and design schema for the user details collection. Is it advisable to use USER_NAME as the object_id in user details collection? What are all the Pros and Cons of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only database restriction is that the _id has to be unique. You can use anything you like.

Only thing to consider off the top of my head is references to the user.
If you have lots and lots of rows, you'll likely end up holding a references to the user document. It might be beneficial using a objectid rather than the a username. An objectid is 12 bytes.

Sam

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will go with ObjectID.